# How to retrive data from two tables in SQL and populate textboxes in ASP webpage?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

```
USE [Apartmentmanagementsystem]
GO
/****** Object: StoredProcedure [dbo].[userview] Script Date: 6/15/2018 7:52:10 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[userview]
@tenant_id int

as 
BEGIN 

    select * 
    from Tenant  
    join Lease on Tenant.tenant_id=Lease.tenant_id 
    where Tenant.tenant_id=@tenant_id;

END
```

that is my stored procedure.

C# code is

```
SqlConnection constring = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=MOSH-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Apartmentmanagementsystem;Integrated Security=True");
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                clear();


                   if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["id"]))
                {

                    int tenant_id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
                    if (constring.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    {
                        constring.Open();
                        SqlDataAdapter sqda = new SqlDataAdapter("userview", constring);
                        sqda.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        sqda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tenant_id", tenant_id);
                        DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
                        sqda.Fill(dtbl);
                        hftenant_id.Value = tenant_id.ToString();
                        if (dtbl.Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            txtFName.Text = dtbl.Rows[0][1].ToString();
                            txtLName.Text = dtbl.Rows[0][2].ToString();
                            txtPhone.Text = dtbl.Rows[0][3].ToString();
                            txtEmail.Text = dtbl.Rows[0][4].ToString();
                            txtAge.Text = dtbl.Rows[0][5].ToString();
                            ddlGender.Items.FindByValue(dtbl.Rows[0][6].ToString()).Selected = true;
                            txtSdate.Text = dtbl.Rows[0][7].ToString();
                            txtEdate.Text = dtbl.Rows[0][8].ToString();
                            txtDeposit.Text = dtbl.Rows[0][9].ToString();
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

        }
        public void clear()
        {
            txtFName.Text = txtLName.Text = txtPhone.Text = txtEmail.Text = txtAge.Text = ddlGender.Text = txtSdate.Text = txtEdate.Text = txtDeposit.Text = "";
            hftenant_id.Value = "";
        }
        protected void btnSave1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                if (constring.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    constring.Open();
                SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SPnew1", constring);
                sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tenant_id", Convert.ToInt32(hftenant_id.Value == "" ? "0" : hftenant_id.Value));
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@F_Name", txtFName.Text.Trim());
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@L_Name", txtLName.Text.Trim());
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", txtPhone.Text.Trim());
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text.Trim());
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", txtAge.Text.Trim());
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", ddlGender.SelectedValue);
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lease_id", 0);
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@initial_date", txtSdate.Text.Trim());
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end_date", txtEdate.Text.Trim());
                sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@deposit", txtDeposit.Text.Trim());
                sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                clear();

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                constring.Close();
            }
```

The issues is that when I type in the `id`, example `?id=1` it displays but the `Tenant` table pushes the contents of `lease` out of place.

I think the issue is the dropdown list.

How do I retrieve data from the two SQL tables and populate the textboxes in an ASP webpage?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing it, but I don't see anything in your code about a dropdown list. I'd start with verifying your sproc is returning the correct values.  You may want to look at explicitly state your values in your select instead of using *.

Comment: the drop down list is ddlGender.after its value has been displayed for some reason create_date of Tenant table which is not supposed to be there takes the place of initial_date the first value of table Lease thus pushing everything below ddl gender out of place.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the UI.. you need to send the aspx code or add the code to the GIT repository.
To begin with.. use html table

```
 <table>
  <tr>
    <td>Gender: </td>
    <td> <asp:dropdownlist....></asp:dropdownlist> </td>
    <td>other : </td>
    <td> <asp:textbox..some other control..></asp:dropdownlist> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">your data grid / html shoudl go here to display data from your 
    stored procedure. <td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

Feel free to add comments if you need any futher help, adding your aspx page woudl help getting more specific answer for your question.

Comment: thanks for the above but my issue is that the first field from Lease is thrown from its text box by create date which is date.now() and not supposed to be there and so the first value from Lease displaces the next from its textbox and so  and miss the last value entirely

Comment: ok i think i acutually geting you because i am not using table i am drag and dropping textboxes.but then why is there data at all retrieved